# Regex - Oman Mobile No

Tags: regex

this regex is working ok for oman mobile number,s

```
^(\+968|968|00968)?\d{8}$
```

Oman Country Code `+968`
and 8 digit mobile number,

Mobile Numbers starts with 2,7,9
I want to edit this regex to force numbers starting with 2,7 & 9

I've tried to add `[22-6]|[71-2]|[78-9]|[901-9]|[91-9]` which are the mobile codes of different regions of oman.

`^(\+968|968|00968)[2|7|9]?\d{8}$` tried to do it simple but it doesn't accepts mobile with out country codes it should accepts 8 number digit starting with 2 or 7 or 9

Comment: Like this? `^(?:(?:\+?968|00968)\d{8}|[279]\d{7})$` https://regex101.com/r/7LXmhP/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your explanations, it should be: `^((\+|00)?968)?[279]\d{7}$`

https://regex101.com/r/4d2QNb/5

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't accepts mobile numbers without country code

Comment: Thank you, It's great now It is working perfectly

^((\+|00)?968)?(2|7|9)\d{7}$

Answer (score 2):

You can optionally match `00` or `+` followed by the county code using non capturing groups. Then match 2, 7, 9 and 7 digits

```
^(?:(?:\+|00)?968)?[279]\d{7}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\+|00)?` Optionally match `+` or `00`
  - `968` Match literally
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `[279]\d{7}` Match either 2, 7, 9 and 7 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbm8ho/1)

Comment: This also matches eg `9681`, `+9681` and `009681`, whereas I understood, that after the country code, only 2, 7 or 9 are allowed. See https://regex101.com/r/7LXmhP/2/

Comment: @The fourth bird Even after you edited after my comment, it is still not working, it is still matching my examples given in the before comment,.

Comment: It's great but it accepts +96811111111
Country Code is optional which can be +968 or 00968 or 968
mobile numbers are 8 digits and will be started with 2 or 7 or 9

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Ah yes, I see. My answer is wrong. It should be `^(?:(?:\+|00)?968)?[279]\d{7}$`

Answer (score 0):

with small modification in your regex.

```
(?:|968)[279]\d{7}$
```

Comment: This is not catching mobile numbers without country code